# How can I initialise Twitter's widget.js SDK with my Twitter API ID?

Tags: javascript, twitter

Current code is:

`$.getScript('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', function() {
  twttr.widgets.load();
});`

But I want to pass in my Twitter API Key as an initialisation variable.

For example, with Facebook, you do:

`$.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_AU/all.js#xfbml=1', function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: 736487365874365873
  });
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a Twitter API key initialisation (appart from the the Twitter OAuth applications access and the usual HTML `data-*` attributes, for example `data-widget-id`), but if you worry about the *number of allowed impressions*, you should check out the Twitter API terms:

https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms

i.e. this part:

> If your application will eventually need more than 1 million user
>   tokens,  or you expect your embedded Tweets and embedded timelines to
>   exceed 10 million daily impressions,  you will need to talk to us
>   directly about your access to the Twitter API as you may be subject to
>   additional terms.
>
> Furthermore, applications that attempt to replicate
>   Twitter’s core user experience (as described in Section I.5 below) 
>   will need our permission to have more than 100,000 user tokens and are
>   subject to additional terms.

Comment: in which case, you're saying that for JavaScript Interfaces (not including OAuth) there's no requirement to associate your webpage with the correct Twitter App Id?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. If it were necessary I would expect to see it in the generated widgets codes from the offical tools. It just says *Add any public Twitter timeline to your website using the tool below. Simply select your timeline source, options, and copy and paste the code in the HTML of your page.* - where the widgets got their special data-widget-id HTML attribute. It looks like they monitor it through these id's.